# rosmake rosjava.android

Tags: rosjava, android, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using UBUNTU 10.04 and i was successfully able to install ROS Electric and ROSJAVA. I was able to run ROSJAVA pub/sub examples without any error, I am now trying to install rosjava.android from hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.android/ rosjava.android and when I do rosmake rosjava.android I am getting the following error

Not sure what to do. There are so many installation pages with different instructions. Not sure which one is correct.

Please help

Regards
GOPI

=============

### {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap make.py android_rosserial
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 108, in 
main(sys.argv)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 100, in main
build(rospack, package)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 57, in build
maven.write_ant_maven_dependencies(rospack, package, stream)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 298, in write_ant_maven_dependencies
_write_maven_dependencies_group(rospack, package, 'compile', stream)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 255, in _write_maven_dependencies_group
_map_package_dependencies(rospack, package, export_operator, scope=scope)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 105, in _map_package_dependencies
_map_exports(rospack, dependency, export_operator, _transtive_dependency_scope_check, scope)
File "/home/gopi/ros_workspace/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 86, in _map_exports
package_directory = roslib.packages.get_pkg_dir(package)
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/packages.py", line 220, in get_pkg_dir
raise InvalidROSPkgException("Cannot locate installation of package %s: %s. ROS_ROOT[%s] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[%s]"%(package, rperr.strip(), ros_root, ros_package_path))
roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: Cannot locate installation of package parsec_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [parsec_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gopi/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12477/rosmake-rosjava.android/) by [gopinath](https://answers.ros.org/users/1580/gopinath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind. I fixed the problem by deleting the android_rosserial from rosjava.android. I am not sure this is required but I can get past and can compile all packages

---

Originally posted by [gopinath](https://answers.ros.org/users/1580/gopinath/) with karma: 31 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0